# Age group counts using birthdate

Tags: sql, hadoop

I want to be able to get counts on each age group below using the customer's birthday. The customer also has to meet certain conditions. I need to use 2 tables.

```
18 to 25
26 to 35
36 to 45
46 to 55
56 to 65
65 and over
```

using the following table and columns:

```
BRTH_DT - birthday
MSTR_CUST - customer table where BRTH_DT is
MSTR_ACT - account table where BR_CD is
BR_CD - code , I want to include all customer with code like '%00%'
CUST_ODT - customer open date from customer table, I want to include dates between '2017-11-01' and '2017-11-30'
```

I have tried a few syntax but it doesn't work. I am using Hadoop.

Query:

```
SELECT  (
  CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) BETWEEN 18 AND 25
      THEN '18-25'
    ELSE
      CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) BETWEEN 26 AND 35
          THEN '26-35'
        ELSE
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) BETWEEN 36 AND 45
              THEN '36-45'
            ELSE
              CASE
                WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) BETWEEN 46 AND 55
                  THEN '46-55'
                ELSE
                  CASE
                    WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) BETWEEN 56 AND 65
                      THEN '56-65'
                    ELSE
                      CASE
                        WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) > 65
                          THEN '65andOver'
  END) from MSTR_ACCT_A JOIN MSTR_CUST B
  where B.CUST_ODT between '2017-11-01' and '2017-11-30' and A.BR_CD like '%00%';
```

Comment: Hi ramonesfan, to improve your question, you should include in your question the query that wasn't working. Describe what is going wrong. Are you getting an error? Unexpected results?

Comment: I have my query below that does not work. I gt he query from this site as well. I may have misused the syntax.

Comment: what are you using in hadoop? are you using hive? can you post a sample of the files?

Comment: @shainnif - Yes..im using hive, I'm pretty new to this so still discovering

Answer (score 0):

The query provided below should do the same thing that yours is aiming to do. I simplified your case when statements. I'm not sure if nesting case statements is a syntax error, but it overly complicates things. I also added a name to the column that will be created.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) BETWEEN 18 AND 25
      THEN '18-25'
    WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) BETWEEN 26 AND 35
      THEN '26-35'
    WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) BETWEEN 36 AND 45
      THEN '36-45'
    WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) BETWEEN 46 AND 55
      THEN '46-55'
    WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) BETWEEN 56 AND 65
      THEN '56-65'
    WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (select sysdate from dual)) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM BRTH_DT) > 65
      THEN '65andOver'
    END AS Age_Range
FROM MSTR_ACCT_A JOIN MSTR_CUST B
WHERE B.CUST_ODT BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30' AND A.BR_CD LIKE '%00%';
```

Comment: thank you for providing the syntax. I tried it and I am getting the same error I got - Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'sysdate'

Comment: another error - Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:23 cannot recognize input near 'YEAR' 'FROM' '(' in select expression

Comment: Oh those parentheses shouldn't be there, I didn't notice that before, see edited answer

Comment: @ramonesfan Your syntax for Extract is wrong as well, you need to use `EXTRACT (<timestamp>, YEAR)`. I can't tell what variable you want to use for your timestamp. I'm not sure what sysdate, dual, and BRTH_DT are. If BRTH_DT is a timestamp in either MSTR_ACCT_A or MSTR_CUST, then you should use `EXTRACT (BRTH_DT, YEAR)` for example.